# PHP: assigning values to object properties in the skeleton vs __construct

Tags: php, oop

Is there a difference between

```
class foo {
    public $bar = 'baz';
     }
```

and

```
class foo {

    public $bar;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->bar = 'baz';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

### Yes there is a difference...

Always use the **`constructor`** way of initializing the variables. Below example throws an error on your first method.

```
class foo {
    public $bar = $_POST['foo']; //Error will be thrown
     }
```

---

```
class foo {

    public $bar;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->bar = $_POST['foo']; // Works just fine
    }
}
```

Comment: But is there a difference if setting it directly like his example? Using variables outside of a method throws an error and in that example, this answer is correct.

Comment: Yeah you are right, but it's always a good practice to initialize the variables on your `constructor`

Answer (score 1):

Initially there is no any diference..

Answer (score 0):

Not that I'm aware of. PHP doesn't have any concept of `final` like java does, so the method can be changed any time. Whether you do it in a constructor or not doesn't influence anything

Answer (score 0):

Using parameter is the way how to maximize the concept of Constructor,

such as:

```
class foo {

    private $bar;

    public function __construct($bar)
    {
        $this->bar = $bar;
    }

    public function getBar()
    {
        return $this->bar;
    }
}

$foo = new foo("daison12006013");
echo $foo->getBar();
```